# Kotlin Flow "First Offline" approach

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am developing a brand new android app and i wanted to implement an Offline-First strategy using Kotlin Flow just like we do it using RxJava. i use below code for the offline-first functionality when i use Rx.

```
private fun getOfflineFirst(param: Param): Observable<T> =
    Observable.concatArrayEagerDelayError(
        getOffline(param), getRemote(param)
```

getOffline and getRemote functions will return an observable object.
and i use below code to achieve same result using Flow.

```
private suspend fun getOfflineFirst(param: Param) = flow {
    getLocal(param)
        .onCompletion {
            getRemote(param).collect {
                emit(it)
            }
        }.collect { emit(it) }
}
```

getLocal and getRemote will return a Flow object. also i use another logic in one of my playground projects like below:

```
    suspend fun getResult(param: PARAM, strategy: QueryStrategy): Flow<ResultResponse> = flow {
    if (strategy.isRemote()) {
        emit(getRemoteResult(param))
    } else {
        emit(getLocalResult(param))
        emit(getRemoteResult(param))
    }
}
```

In the "else" section it's going to emit the local result then the remote, that's how i handled first-offline in this scenario.

But i am not sure if i am using the best approaches available.

Can someone suggest me some better approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Use this abstract class to handle data fetching and storing.

```
  /**
  * A repository which provides resource from local database as well as remote 
   endpoint.
  *
  * [RESULT] represents the type for database.
  * [REQUEST] represents the type for network.
  */
  @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
  abstract class NetworkBoundRepository<RESULT, REQUEST> {

   fun asFlow() = flow<State<RESULT>> {

    // Emit Loading State
    emit(State.loading())

    try {
        // Emit Database content first
        emit(State.success(fetchFromLocal().first()))

        // Fetch latest posts from remote
        val apiResponse = fetchFromRemote()

        // Parse body
        val remotePosts = apiResponse.body()

        // Check for response validation
        if (apiResponse.isSuccessful && remotePosts != null) {
            // Save posts into the persistence storage
            saveRemoteData(remotePosts)
        } else {
            // Something went wrong! Emit Error state.
            emit(State.error(apiResponse.message()))
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Exception occurred! Emit error
        emit(State.error("Network error! Can't get latest data."))
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    // Retrieve posts from persistence storage and emit
    emitAll(fetchFromLocal().map {
        State.success<RESULT>(it)
    })
}

/**
 * Saves retrieved from remote into the persistence storage.
 */
@WorkerThread
protected abstract suspend fun saveRemoteData(response: REQUEST)

/**
 * Retrieves all data from persistence storage.
 */
@MainThread
protected abstract fun fetchFromLocal(): Flow<RESULT>

/**
 * Fetches [Response] from the remote end point.
 */
@MainThread
protected abstract suspend fun fetchFromRemote(): Response<REQUEST>
}
```

> and in your repo class pass your api interface and database repo

```
class Repository(private val api: ApiInterface, private val db: DBRepository) {

/**
 * Fetched the posts from network and stored it in database. At the end, data from 
 persistence
 * storage is fetched and emitted.
 */
fun getAllArticles(): Flow<State<List<Article>>> {
    return object : NetworkBoundRepository<List<Article>, ArticlesResponse>() {

        override suspend fun saveRemoteData(response: ArticlesResponse) =
                db.getNewsDao().insertALLItems(response.article!!)

        override fun fetchFromLocal(): Flow<List<Article>> = 
      db.getNewsDao().getItems()

        override suspend fun fetchFromRemote(): Response<ArticlesResponse> = 
        api.getArticles()

      }.asFlow().flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! i already did something like this. but for the sake of clarity i don't use any error handling in the flow, but i use catch for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

First, it depends how much variability you would like to have. Second, there is Dropbox's [Store](https://github.com/dropbox/store) solution and it is more universal (and complex) solution for these issues.

I do not understand much your first function getOfflineFirst, it could be done similarly as in your second example in else branch.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest that approach. First it would not be a good choice to `collect()` from another `flow` in another `flow`. Second, you have to decide between `Rx` and `Flow` you don't need both of them.

You can always use the `map()` method for that.
I would do something like this:

```
getData() = getLocal(param)
   .map{ whatGetLocalReturns ->
     return@map getRemote(param)
    }
   .map{ whatGetRemoteReturns ->
     return@map decideResult(whatGetRemoteReturns, strategy)
   }
```

And then you can do:

```
getData().collect{ result ->
  // there you go :) 
}
```

I have skipped some details but I believe you can figure out what I exactly mean. Don't forget the threading and everything of course.